# When upgrading opencart to a newer version, do we also need to update the plugins and the codes?

Tags: php, plugins, opencart

I am a beginner just started learning Opencart and its environment at my workplace. I was advised to upgrade my Opencart 1.5 to the latest version due to the update of PHP 5.6 in the hosting server. I want to find out, if we upgrade the Opencart to the latest version, do we also need to update the plugins?? Also can anyone share a good link to help me understand better with the Opencart upgrade and plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each OpenCart version has some unique features which means one version's extension may not work with the other version.So the answer is you will have to rewrite the extension.Use OpenCart forums to check each versions breaking changes and new coding syntax.
Example in OpenCart versions below 2.3.x in order to pass values to the view from the controller, you simply need to assign your data to the `$this->data` variable, which is essentially an array of `key => value pairs`. As an example

```
$this->data['example_var'] = 123;
```

In OpenCart 2.3.x+ changed to `$data['example_var'] = 123;`
Check each version to be assured.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply ovicko. Now i have a clear picture.